# Disable Doctrine Timestampable auto-updating the `updatedAt` field on certain update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony2 project, I have a Doctrine entity that has a `datetime` field, called `lastAccessed`. Also, the entity uses [Timestampable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) on `updatedAt` field.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo
;

class MyEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $lastAccessed;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

}
```

I need to update the field `lastAccessed` without also updating the `updatedAt` field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestampable is just doctrine behavior so is executed every time when you use an ORM. 
In my opinion the simplest way is just using DBAL layer and raw sql query.

For example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table set last_accessed = :lastAccess where id = :id";
//set parameters 
$params['lastAccess'] = new \DateTime();
$params['id'] = $some_id;
$stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

You can of course put it into proper repository class

Comment: There is no cleaner solution ?
It would be nice to easily be able to disable the auto-update feature..

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled upon this as well and came up with this solution:

```
public function disableTimestampable()
{
    $eventManager = $this->getEntityManager()->getEventManager();
    foreach ($eventManager->getListeners('onFlush') as $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener) {
            $eventManager->removeEventSubscriber($listener);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Something very similar can be used to disable the blamable behavior as well of course.

Answer (score 5):

There is also an easy way (or more proper way) how to do it, just override listener.

first create interface which will be implemented by entity

```
interface TimestampableCancelInterface
{

   public function isTimestampableCanceled(): bool;

}
```

than extend Timestampable listener and override `updateField`.
this way we can disable all all events or with `cancelTimestampable` define custom rules for cancellation based on entity state.

```
class TimestampableListener extends \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
{

    protected function updateField($object, $eventAdapter, $meta, $field)
    {
        /** @var \Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\ClassMetadata $meta */
        $property = $meta->getReflectionProperty($field);
        $newValue = $this->getFieldValue($meta, $field, $eventAdapter);

        if (!$this->isTimestampableCanceled($object)) {
            $property->setValue($object, $newValue);
        }
    }

    private function isTimestampableCanceled($object): bool
    {
        if(!$object instanceof TimestampableCancelInterface){
            return false;
        }

        return $object->isTimestampableCanceled();
    }

}
```

implement interface. Most simple way is to just set property for this

```
private $isTimestampableCanceled = false;

public function cancelTimestampable(bool $cancel = true): void
{
    $this->isTimestampableCanceled = $cancel;
}

public function isTimestampableCanceled():bool {
    return $this->isTimestampableCanceled;
}
```

or define rules like you want

last thing is to not set default listener but ours. 
I'm using symfony so:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
    class:
      timestampable:  <Namespace>\TimestampableListener
```

Than you can just do

```
$entity = new Entity;
$entity->cancelTimestampable(true)
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush(); // and you will get constraint violation since createdAt is not null :D
```

This way can be timestamps disabled per single entity not for whole onFlush. Also custom behavior is easy to apply based on entity state.